# Strange URL with Google Maps API Javascript v3

Tags: cordova, google-maps-api-3

My Cordova application uses Google Maps API javascript to display map in a HTML page.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
```

Whenever the page is loaded, device web browser is launched automatically with a very strange URL:
https://www.google.com/maps/api/js/master?pb=!1m2!1u18!2s9!2sen-US!3sUS!4s18/9

If I change the reference with version parameter, this issue is resolved.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.17&sensor=false"></script>
```

I think this happen since Google updated version 3.18 on Sep 18.
Anyone can confirm with me if this is a Google Maps API issue or not. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I did not put my code here because I think it is not necessary.

Comment: I notice that today I recheck and found that issue already fixed. I do not see any change in the Google Maps API change log, but I think Google already fixed it silently. Thanks.